# OpenNMS threshold checks only one server

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, snmpd, opennms

So I'm trying to configure OpenNMS to check the disk space on my linux servers.

After some work I got it to check one server through SNMP : 
I installed snmpd on the server I'm monitoring, defined a threshold(in fact I use the predefined default one) and connected it to an event that triggers when ns-dskPercent goes to high. up until here all went well.

Now I added a second server, installed the same stuff on it, it seems to monitor the snmp daemon and notifies me when the service is down, but it doesn't seem to see the threshold.

When I make changes in the threshold - for example lower it to 20% in order to force it to trigger - only the first server sees that it changed (and also gives a notification that the configuration has changed) and fires the alarm, but the second server doesn't respond.

(These are the notifications I get on the first server:)

```
High threshold rearmed for SNMP datasource ns-dskPercent on interface 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, parms: label="/" ds="ns-dskPercent" description="ns-dskPercent" 
value="NaN (the threshold definition has been changed)" instance="1"
instanceLabel="_root_fs" resourceId="node[9].dskIndex[_root_fs]" 
threshold="20.0" trigger="1" rearm="75.0" reason="Configuration has been changed" 


High threshold exceeded for SNMP datasource ns-dskPercent on interface 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, parms: label="/" ds="ns-dskPercent" description="ns-dskPercent" 
value="52" instance="1" instanceLabel="_root_fs" 
resourceId="node[9].dskIndex[_root_fs]" threshold="20.0" trigger="1" rearm="75.0"
```

Any ideas why or how I can make the second server to respond also?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be based upon the source of the data collected.  Thresholding in modern versions of OpenNMS (14+) is evaluated inline and in memory as data is collected, so you must ensure that the threshold is evaluated against the exact metrics the node you are interested in contains.

There are usually two forms that file system metrics on linux systems come in- mib2 use of the host resources table (hrStorageSize, etc in $OPENNMS_HOME/etc/datacollection/mib2.xml) or net-snmp metrics from the net-snmp MIB (ns-dskTotal, etc in $OPENNMS_HOME/etc/datacollection/netsnmp.xml).

So, first verify that you are getting good data from the new server and that it is, indeed, collecting metrics from the same MIB table that you seek to threshold against.

Comment: Not sure if that's the solution. it's already defined in netsnmp.xml as you suggested, and I can also see that all the data is saved if I graph it through the web interface.